# Eliminate all data above 95th percentile from a dataset

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have dataset where I want to eliminate all data above 95th percentile of a variable, let's say 'col1'. I have used np.quantile method to calculate 95th percentile data and filtered all value below than this data.

```
df_95 = df[df['col1'] <  np.quantile(df['col1'], 0.95)]
```

The problem I am facing is that there are multiple datas with the 95th percentile value in the variable, and my code is removing data from the first instance of it.
Whereas I want it to do it from exact 95th percentile only.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO - can you provide a sample input and the expected output?

Comment: Please clarify as to what data isn't being removed from your data frame by that filter.

Comment: I have a dataset where 95th percentile value of a column is 10800.
ex.. [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ............,10500, _10800_, 10800, 10800, **10800**, 10800, .......]
The value in bold is the 95th percentile value.
When I am using the code to remove all value above 95th percentile, it removes all value from first instance of 10800(mentioned in italic).
the result dataset is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ............,10500]. What is want my output to be [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ............,10500, _10800_, 10800, 10800].
Due to which I am left with 94.95% of data, instead of 95%.

Comment: I voted to close this till the OP can include sample input data and the expected output, @AkhileshPanigrahi read [How to make good reproducible pandas example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).